# Show 'Additional Details' section on Magento Product page before Description

Tags: php, magento

So on a page like this: http://liff2013.com/screenings/blancanieves.html

We want the 'Event Snapshot' section to be posted before the Director/Writer/Cast section.

I'm not a pro with PHP, but I think this is the code that calls the other code which builds the table. (This code is in my view.phtml file)

```
<?php foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html):?>

    <div class="box-collateral <?php echo "box-{$alias}"?>">
        <?php if ($title = $this->getChildData($alias, 'title')):?>
        <h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h2>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php echo $html; ?>
    </div>
```

And here is some code I found in my attributes.phtml file:

```
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
<h2><?php echo $this->__('Event Snapshot') ?></h2>
<table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
    <col width="25%" />
    <col />
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
        <tr>
            <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
            <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! We basically just want it to call/populate the box-additional div before the box-description one.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the layout file of your product detail page..?
I think you need have to change your phtml, changes in block position in layout would do the job.....

EDIT : 
You have to modify your layout file which is catalog.xml as below :

in `<catalog_product_view translate="label">` handle you have to shift the

`<block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />`

above of

`<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">`

This might solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry the formatting was weird for this page when I tried to enter it into stackoverflow as code, but here is a .txt file with the code: http://liff2013.com/view.txt

Comment: Thank you so much! I worked on this for a solid 2 hours with no luck, but your answer worked! I could kiss you! =p

Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome...just accept the answer n vote up so that others facing same problem will get help...